# Здравствуйте, у меня есть одна ошибка в коде на discord.py мне пишет ошибка ниже

Tags: discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open('serversusers.json', 'r') as f:
        serversusers = json.load(f)

    await update_data(serversusers, message.author)
    await add_experience(serversusers, message.author, 5)
    await level_up(serversusers, message.author, message.channel)

    with open('serversusers.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(serversusers, f)

async def update_data(serversusers, user):
    if not 'user.id' in serversusers:
        serversusers['user.id'] = {}
        serversusers['user.id']['experience'] = 0
        serversusers['user.id']['level'] = 1

async def add_experience(serversusers, user, exp):
    serversusers['user.id']['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(serversusers, user, channel):
    experience = serversusers['user.id']['experience']
    lvl_start = serversusers['user.id']['level']
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))

    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await client.send_message(channel, '{} Вы получили новый уровень {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
        serversusers['user.id']['level'] = lvl_end
```

вот ошибка

```
await client.send_message(channel, '{} Вы получили новый уровень {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'send_message'
```

Comment: В заголовке нужно описывать свет проблемы или ошибки, а не заниматься эпистолярным жанром.

Answer (score 0):

В [документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) есть при того, как отправлять сообщения в ивенте `on_message`

```
if lvl_start < lvl_end:
    await message.channel.send(channel, '{} Вы получили новый уровень {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
    serversusers['user.id']['level'] = lvl_end
```

Comment: привет, скорее всего вы правы, но вот проблема. Сейчас у меня проблема в message.channel.send клиент не видит значение message. что мне стоит добавить в строку async def help(сюда) чтобы данной ошибки не было

Comment: Какой клиент, пишите конкретнее

Comment: клиент, то есть сам бот

Comment: А ответ выше для кого?

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка в этой команде:

```py
await client.send_message(channel, '{} Вы получили новый уровень {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
```

В чём суть ошибки... Вы пытаетесь отправить этот текст в неизвестно куда, то есть в сам клиент бота ( так нельзя:/ )
И поэтому вам надо просто найти канал, там где отправлялось сообщение, то есть `await message.channel.send`
Надеюсь помог

Comment: привет, скорее всего вы правы, но вот проблема. Сейчас у меня проблема в message.channel.send клиент не видит значение message. что мне стоит добавить в строку async def help(сюда) чтобы данной ошибки не было

Comment: Тогда попробуйте `channel.send`